# How to define mail from and host settings in Websphere 6.1 for Java application

Tags: email, smtp, java, grep, websphere

Working with some older WAS 6.1 hosts (fix pack 25), and have a java app that sends mail from one host with a mail from field:

nobody@nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com [mailto:nobody@nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com]

In another environment, it's sending mail with the from field:  wasuser@hostname.acme.com
This is the only application that is installed within this WAS profile.

On the WAS 6.1 admin console, I've examined:

Resources | Mail | Mail sessions | Mail from  & Mail store host (both Mail from and Mail store host are blank)

In order for mails to be sent from: acme@coyote.com should Mail from=acme and Mail store host=coyote.com?

In what config files do these values get defined in the WAS 6.1 directory/config file structure?  Could I edit the configuration files, then restart WAS 6.1 via command line?

I would expect these mail header fields could/should be defined in the java application as well?  Is there a properties file where java apps typically configure mail from and host values?  I may need to try grepping through some .properties files within the application ear directory.

The version of grep on the older system (SunOS 5.8) doesn't seem to recurse, so I've been trying to combine grep and find with backticks (may be doing this wrong) to find a potential config file in WAS_HOME:

```
grep "wasuser" `find . -name "*" -print -exec file {} \;`
```

No luck yet via [IBM documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp)  Thanks for suggestions in advance..